# how to use join 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-insert

I have 3 tables T1,T2,T3
table T1 contain 2 column(key,class/student) the column class/student contains both classes and student for example(english,math,mark,tom,..)
table T2 contain 2 column(class,student)each class have more than one student in it, and this 2 column use the key from T1.
Now in Table T3 i want to insert a specific class with its student in column A for class and B for students kowing that this columns use the key from T1
i tried this but it returns the specific class with its students but one lign is repeted a lot of time:

```
INSERT INTO T3 (A,B) 

SELECT m.class, m.student FROM T1 b,T2 m
WHERE m.class=(select key from T1 where class/student='English') AND b.KEY = m.student ;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

use explicit join not coma separated join , it seems to me you are trying like below query

```
INSERT INTO T3 (A,B)    
SELECT m.class, m.student FROM T1 a
    join T1 b on  a."key"=b."key"
    join 
    T2 m on a."key"=m.student
    WHERE m.class in (select "key" from T1 where class='English')
```

Comment: it gives a.key invalid identifier

Comment: @Blue do you have key column in table T1

Comment: ora-01747 : invalid  user.table.column , table.column or column specification

Comment: @Blue sorry i mistaken use [] it should be double quote

Comment: ora-00904 : "b"."key": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
INSERT INTO T3 (A , B)    
SELECT M.class, M.student 
FROM T1 X Join T1 Y ON X.key = Y.key
Join T2 Z ON X.key = M.student
WHERE M.Class IN (SELECT key FROM T1 WHERE class ='English')
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and @zaynul's answer

Comment: Very simple.. Both are from different places